# Security updates for End of life d8 version

Tags: 8

I have been tasked with updating a site that was at 8.2.7 to 8.2.8 to fix the security item listed at: https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2017-04-19/drupal-core-critical-access-bypass and the apply critical updates.

I had to do this core update manually because the `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` call didn't actually do anything.

I can't update straight to 8.3/4/5 due to a host of custom coded modules which target 3rd party APIs and have dependencies on contributed modules.

I am going to have to update Drupal core incrementally and apply critical updates for the given version and check nothing is broken.

**So my question is this**:

I have just updated manually from 8.2.7 to 8.2.8. I inherited the site and there is no documentation of what critical updates have been applied to Drupal in the past.

Is there any way I can get a list of the Security updates I need to apply for a given Drupal version (*Does a drush or Drupal console command exist that would check the current installation and list .updates required?*) and if not how would I go about determining what needs applying ?

Comment: `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` is your composer.json correct? This command updates Drupal for me.

Comment: that command did run and my json entry for core was locaked at 8.2.8 but after running and then doing drush updb and entup there was nothing to update and drush status showed drupal still at 8.2.7

Comment: 8.2.8 is installed fine now though. Just need to know if there is a way to get a list of security updates outstanding.

Comment: 8.2.8 is the latest (last?) version in the 8.2.* release. If your site is on that version, then all security updates that your constraints will allow you to apply are already installed, by definition (unless I've misunderstood you?). The latest high critical security patch (https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2017-08-16/drupal-core-multiple) was only released for 8.3.*, so you're out of luck with that one, SA-CORE-2018-002 is your last patch. You could try getting the patches for more recent versions and applying them manually, but obviously YMMV